# ¿Qué hace Object obj{}?

Tags: c++, constructor

He visto en un [comentario en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34403565/956880) que estas dos líneas hacen cosas distintas :

```
Object obj;
Object obj{};
```

Tengo claro que la primera declara una variable de clase Object y la construye con el constructor sin parámetros.
Pero, ¿qué hace la segunda?. En más de 10 años programando en C++ nunca lo había visto, ¿es algo nuevo de c++11 o 14?

Comment: La explicación estaba más abajo en otra respuesta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404267/186133

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En C++03 había varias formas de inicializar elementos e intercambiarlas podía alterar el funcionamiento del programa. Además dichas inicializaciones poseían ciertas limitaciones.

Debido a lo anterior, en [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) se tomaron dos medidas para corregir o, al menos, intentar paliar esta problemática: Por un lado se han uniformizado los constructores y, por otra, se ha añadido la posibilidad de inicializar elementos a partir de listas.

**Uniformidad de constructores**

Ahora, además de la construcción tradicional con paréntesis, pueden usarse las llaves para llamar a los constructores de una clase. La ventaja sobre el constructor tradicional es que puede apoyarse en el *inicializador de listas* si así se requiere. Esto permite, por ejemplo, inicializar todos los miembros de una estructura en una sola línea aunque no haya un constructor específico:

```
struct POO
{
  int entero;
  std::string cadena;
  double decimal;
};

POO miObjeto{7,"test",10.56};
```

Esta actualización permite código que a simple vista puede parecer más bien extraño para un habitual de versiones anteriores de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), como crear un objeto sin indicar explícitamente el tipo:

```
struct POO
{
  int entero;
  std::string cadena;
  double decimal;
};

POO func()
{
  return {7,"test",10.56};
}
```

Huelga decir que para que el código anterior funcione el compilador tiene que hacer uso de la segunda característica que he comentado, el *inicializador de listas*.

**Inicializador de listas**

Imaginemos que queremos construir un arreglo de tamaño 5 con 5 valores iniciales. Al ser un elemento que se ajusta a la definición POD (*Plain Old Data*), el estándar C++03 permitía definir sus valores usando una inicialización como la siguiente:

```
int valores[] = {5,12,3,-1,10};
```

Ahora intentamos hacer lo mismo pero con un `std::vector`. Ahora no podemos usar las llaves, por lo que tenemos que recurrir a una secuencia algo más compleja y engorrosa:

```
// opción 1
std::vector<int> valores;
valores.push_back(5);
valores.push_back(12);
valores.push_back(3);
valores.push_back(-1);
valores.push_back(10);

// opción 2
std::vector<int> valores(5,-1);
int valoresTemp[] = {5,12,3,-1,10};
for( int i=0;i<5;i++ )
  valores.push_back(valoresTemp[i]);
```

El nuevo estándar añade la posibilidad de usar inicializadores de lista en cualquier tipo de objeto. Para ello necesitamos declarar un constructor con una firma similar a la siguiente:

```
MiObjeto::MiObjeto(std::initializer_list<int> valores);
```

Como detalle a destacar cabe mencionar que el tipo de `std::initializer_list` no tiene por qué ser un tipo básico. Este template admite también estructuras más complejas, lo que nos permite inicializar listas complejas con una sintaxis bastante cómoda.

A modo de ejemplo, el caso del vector con [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) quedaría así:

```
std::vector<int> valores = {5,12,3,-1,10};
```

Comment: ¿`std::vector<int> valores {5,12,3,-1,10};` sería válido? Y si lo es, ¿ hace lo mismo que el ejemplo con el `=`?

Comment: Efectivamente sería válido. En el caso de usar el operador `=`, dado que asumo que lo estás usando en el mismo momento de crear el vector el resultado sería exactamente el mismo. Si haces la asignación en otro momento (`valores = {5,12,3,-1,10};`) el efecto será el equivalente a copiar un vector en otro.

Comment: Un inciso @eferion cuando te refieres a POD para la inicialización de estructuras y arreglos en realidad estás hablando de agregados; son los agregados los que se benefician de la inicialización de lista.